# Tablesorter plugin not sorting my tables when data comes from database

Tags: php, jquery

I have the following code:

```
<table id="box-table-a" class="tablesorter">
<thead>
<tr>
<th scope="col">B-House/Dorm Name</th>
<th scope="col">Address</th>
<th scope="col">Price Range</th>
<th scope="col">Date Added</th>
<th scope="col">Status</th>
</tr>
</thead>
 <?php
$q=mysql_query("select * from property");
while( $f=mysql_fetch_array($q, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{                                       $p_id=$f["p_id"];                                    
 echo"
<tbody>
<tr>
<td onblurr='hover2()' onmouseover='hover(".$p_id.")' onclick='showUser(".$p_id.")'>
<span style='cursor:pointer'>".$f['p_name']."</span></td>
<td id='pretty'>".$f['address']."</td>
<td>".$f['p_name']."</td>                           <td>".$f['payment_type']."</td>                         <td>".$status."</td>                                    </tr>       
</tbody>
";
}
?>
</table>
```

Any idea what may be wrong here?

Comment: You said you're using a tablesorter plugin. Can you link us to that plugin so we can get an idea what you're trying to do with it?  Is that a jQuery plugin or a PHP plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't add `<tbody></tbody>` to every loop in the while! Tablesorter is very sensitive.

Comment: hey.. youre so good.. it actually worked... thanks man!! i love you

Comment: hey powtac. can i add you to my skype account? i need to ask question again.. its about jquery tooltip.. ive been working on it for 1 week now..i really need help.

Comment: I would prefer to use Stackoverflow.com. Give it a try! It is much more better than me alone on Skype! And don't forget to vote for good answers.

Comment: hey powtac.. can you check my other question. plesae  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5005654/how-to-modify-my-tooltip-on-a-td

Answer (score 0):

You did'nt sort your DB :

```
$q=mysql_query("select * from property ORDER BY p_name");
```

Comment: I thought this question was about a jQuery plugin; I think that was done on purpose.