# How to modify my tooltip on a td

Tags: jquery

```
<?php

include('db_connect.php');
?><head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="comment-style.css" media="screen" />


<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery.tablesorter/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery.tablesorter/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery-qtip-1.0.0-rc3094652/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery-qtip-1.0.0-rc3094652/jquery.qtip-1.0.0-rc3.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">


    $(document).ready(function(){
    var temp= // i need this to fetch the id of which td i hovered, id of the user not id  //of the td so that i can put the id in the data which will be passed to description-//hover.php
    $("#box-table-a span").qtip({
       content: {
          url: 'description-hover.php',
          data: { id: //this should be temp here },
          method: 'post'
       },
       show: 'mouseover',
       hide: 'mouseout'
    });

    });

    </script>
    <html>

    </head>
    <div id="table-of-data-div"> 
            <div id="table-div">
    <table id="box-table-a" class="tablesorter">
<thead>
<tr>

<th scope="col" style="cursor:pointer;">B-House/Dorm Name</th>
<th scope="col" style="cursor:pointer;">Address</th>
<th scope="col" style="cursor:pointer;">Price Range</th>
<th scope="col" style="cursor:pointer;">Date Added</th>
<th scope="col" style="cursor:pointer;">Status</th>

</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php


$q=mysql_query("select * from property");
    while( $f=mysql_fetch_array($q, MYSQL_ASSOC))
    {
                                            $p_id=$f["p_id"];

    echo"

    <tr>
                                                <td id='tool-table''><input type='hidden' id='tool-id' value='".$p_id."' />

                                                <span style='cursor:pointer'>".$f['p_name']."</span></td>
                                                <td id='pretty'>".$f['address']."</td>
                                                <td>".$f['p_name']."</td>
                                                <td>".$f['payment_type']."</td>      
                                                <td>".$status."</td>       
                                            </tr>       


    ";

    }



    ?>
     </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
    </div>
    </html>
```

Comment: HTML tags are stripped out of posts, you need to make sure HTML is inside a code block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one of the built in jQuery tooltip plugins. http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/index.html

Here's an example of using it with a table: http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tooltip/table.html

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#my-table td").hover(function() {
        $("#property-hover").html("<p>Put some loading text here while the ajax call loads</p>");

        var prop = 0; //TODO: this variable needs to be retrieved from somewhere

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "description-hover.php",
            data: {id:prop},
            success: function(data) {
                $("#property-hover").html(data);
            }
        });  
    });

    $("#my-table td").tooltip({tip: '#property-hover'});
});
```

Comment: jordan.. where did that .tooltip came from? is that from the plugin you mentioned?

Comment: Yes, instructions for downloading and using it are here: http://flowplayer.org/tools/download/index.html

Comment: jordan.. how can i append the data from ajax without using the div#property-hover. since i think tooltip plugin automatically makes the tooltip positioned next to the hovered td.  can i do something like this $("#tool-table").tooltip({tip: 'append(data)'});

Comment: There is a single tooltip element that you would be updating the html for. The tooltip plugin handles the hide and show, so all you have to do is update the html. Whatever the name of your element is, use that instead of "#property-hover" in my example above, then in your success event, do $("#name-of-my-tooltip-container").html(data)

Comment: @jordan: I really dont get what you mean.. please bear with me man. where did .html(data) came from? the id property-hover is the div where i append the data from database which i would like to be displayed in tooltip. Please elaborate more man. Thanks a lot

Comment: @jordan: man i dont think i code is correct. ive modified it a lot of times.. but somehow it updates the html first then display the tip. its so unstable. sometimes it shows many tips when i hover on a single td. sometimes it shows different tip from different td.

Comment: @Belmark: can you put some links to screen shots of what you're seeing?

Comment: @michael: i hope you can help me man.. http://www.facebook.com/home.php#!/photo.php?fbid=1726360092423&set=a.1165466390431.25721.1641053119&theater. ive print screen it fast so i can reply fast and uploaded it in facebook. hit me back man.

Comment: @Belmark: do you have a requirement to do this tooltip with an Ajax call? If not, consider giving the <td> that you want to hover over a title attribute of whatever the tooltip text is supposed to be. Something like <td title="This is the tooltip text">. Your tooltip can then be triggered with "#tool-table").tooltip() and it will automatically pick up the title attribute. You wouldn't need any of your current hover function. This would all be done in a $(document).ready()

Comment: @jordan: man. i dont want a simple tooltip with the title attribute. cause what i need to display inside the tooltip is a profile of a user when hovered on a td.

Comment: I've edited my answer to show what I think you want to do. Honestly I'm sort of shooting in the dark here. You've given us a tiny little chunk of HTML and JavaScript and asked us to write a project for you.

Comment: @jordan: thats my problem there.. the retrieval of var prop. where would i retrieve that if i wont use onmouseover on the td.. but if I use onmouseover on a td, it will conflict with the tooltip plugin since the plugin already handles the hover thingy of the tooltip.

Comment: @jordan: i have modified my code above.. please check it. my tooltip works now but i only need the id of the user to be stored in var temp. which i dont know hot to get from all the td's. please help. im using qtip tooltip plugin now.

Comment: Is it possible for you to write it into the <td> somehow? Put it inside a span, like <td><span style="display:none;">123123</span></td>, and then you could access it from the main hover function with var prop = $("span", this).text()

Comment: ive tried what you said. but it gets all the id of all the tds.. i only need to get 1 id per hover..

Comment: My code is only going to work if you use it like I have in my answer. If you use it outside the context of the hover function, it's going to just get all the spans. The "this" parameter has the effect of limiting where it starts the selection from. "this" should be referring to the <td>, otherwise it'll run through everything on the page. You're going to need to post all your code somewhere. It's impossible to tell what you're doing from my perspective. Put it up on http://jsfiddle.net/, post a link, and we'll give it a go.

Comment: @jordan. my whole code is above. please check it. im using a plugin so i cant use a hover function cause plugin handles it already. thats my only problem now on how to get the id of the user which i hovered.

Comment: @jordan: man can you give me your contact info? like skype or yahooo messenger. cause this what i do all day waiting for someone to reply on my post. :( ive search the net for weeks. i cant find any example that uses ajax as a tooltip content. btw heres my skype bearandbob, and yahoo mark_blackpunta@yahoo.com if you dont feel like giving yours here.

Comment: You can add multiple hover events and they will all get triggered. There is no limit to how many of the same event you can attach. So, you would have the tooltip attaching itself like you have above, and you would have your own custom hover like the one I have, and they would interact with each other. qTip's job is to display the tooltip itself, while your custom hover's job is to alter the content in the tooltip. Your custom hover is going to go grab the id from somewhere, I guess from that hidden input. Check out jQuery's selectors and DOM manipulation section for how to do that.

Comment: I also wanted to point out that having the same id set for multiple elements is invalid HTML and will cause you problems. You have id='tool-id' on every hidden input right now, so you have no way of knowing which one you're going to get. It would likely be the one in the first table row. Instead give it a class name like class="tool-id" and you can select it with $(".tool-id", this), where "this" is done inside of that hover function and is a reference to the table cell (<td>)

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem you're having is that you're using the onmouseover method to do something that Tooltip allows you to do as an event. You really shouldn't be using onmouseover or onclick. Instead, the tooltip function has options for handling events before it's shown.

In this case, I would use the onBeforeShow event to load the tool tip via ajax.

Here's a simple example of how to use onBeforeShow:

```
<td class='user_name'>Michael</td>

function load_user_info(event){
  //functionality to ajaxy load info here
}
$('td.user_name').tooltip({
  ...
  onBeforeShow: load_user_info,
  ...
});
```

I started creating a solution here: http://jsfiddle.net/mimercha/r7Hxf/23/ and ran out of time. Will try to finish the solution later.

Comment: @michael: man i really appreaicate what you've done. but the tooltip is suppose to be somewhat like a profile of a user if i hover a td. can i do this $(.clasname).attr(title,<div>some data from ajax</div> ? please man. This is my final project which will due on end of february. I really need help. Thanks a lot man

Comment: @michael: i see your point there. if im not mistaken. i need to load the tooltip from ajax first before executing the tooltip plugin. right? but if would not use the onmouseover function, how can i get the id of the user which i like his profile to be displayed in the tooltip?

Comment: @Belmark: I didn't realize you needed html. You might be able to store the html in the title, but if you had any quotes, they might conflict with the title attribute. You can continue using the "tip" attribute then and set the value elsewhere. Instead of onmouseover, use the "onBeforeShow" attribute as described in my edit.

Comment: @Belmark, btw: if you find my answer helpful, click on the up arrow next to the number to vote the answer up so that people who have similar problems will see it. and so I get credit for the answer ;) oh and if I solve your problem, click on the check mark under the voting number to designate it as the 'right' answer.

Comment: @michael: i dont understand man why you use title atribute. my tooltip is supposed to be styled(css), not just a normal tooltip. Cause it's supposed to display profile of which one i hover on a td.

Comment: @michael: If you can just modify your code man. i need to get the id of the profile which i hover on a td first. then load its description on a div then show it on a tooltip.

Comment: i dont know any other way to get the value/id of the user other than onmouseover='function(pass the id to the function)'.

Comment: @michael: i have modified my code above.. please check it. my tooltip works now but i only need the id of the user to be stored in var temp. which i dont know hot to get from all the td's. please help. im using qtip tooltip plugin now.

Comment: Hey belmark, I'll admit, I'm a bit confused on what your question is now! Maybe you'd like to create a new question? I think the question regarding how to modify the tool tip I answered in my response. Also, the way to handle mouse over events using jquery is call the jquery function [hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) you can use the jquery function '$().click()' for on click events.

Answer (score 0):

Recommend using the following for creating the tooltips.  This will allow you to include static or ajax loaded content into your tooltips - [jQuery qTip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/)

Comment: that plugin doesnt have guide. and i cant find any ajax related demo.